# IDEA tells me it cannot instantiate; JavaFX has no problems doing that. Where is the bug?

Tags: java, intellij-idea, javafx

By "stealing" code from [here](http://fxexperience.com/2012/01/curve-fitting-and-styling-areachart/) I created a class extending JavaFX's `AreaChart` so as to create a "smoothed lines area chart":

```
/**
 * An {@link AreaChart} with smoothed lines
 *
 * <p>Code totally salvaged from <a
 * href="http://fxexperience.com/2012/01/curve-fitting-and-styling-areachart/"
 * >here</a>.</p>
 *
 * @param <X> x axis data type
 * @param <Y> y axis data type
 */
public class SmoothedAreaChart<X, Y>
    extends AreaChart<X, Y>
{
    public SmoothedAreaChart(@NamedArg("xAxis")final Axis<X> xAxis,
        @NamedArg("yAxis") final Axis<Y> yAxis,
        @NamedArg("data") final ObservableList<Series<X, Y>> data)
    {
        super(xAxis, yAxis, data);
    }

    public SmoothedAreaChart(@NamedArg("xAxis") final Axis<X> xAxis,
        @NamedArg("yAxis") final Axis<Y> yAxis)
    {
        super(xAxis, yAxis);
    }

    @Override
    protected void layoutPlotChildren()
    {
        // Lots, lots of code
    }
}
```

And I use it in an FXML file:

```
<BorderPane xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/8" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1"
    fx:controller="com.github.fge.grappa.debugger.csvtrace.tabs.treedepth.TreeDepthTabDisplay">
    <top>
        <!-- blah -->
    </top>
    <center>
        <SmoothedAreaChart fx:id="chart" legendVisible="false"
            title="Tree depth by line" animated="false">
            <xAxis>
                <NumberAxis fx:id="xAxis" tickUnit="1.0" autoRanging="false"
                    minorTickVisible="false" forceZeroInRange="false"
                    label="Line number"/>
            </xAxis>
            <yAxis>
                <NumberAxis fx:id="yAxis" forceZeroInRange="true"
                    minorTickVisible="false" autoRanging="false"
                    label="Tree depth"/>
            </yAxis>
        </SmoothedAreaChart>
    </center>
</BorderPane>
```

Now, as mentioned in $subject, an `FXMLLoader` has no problems with that; yet, IDEA complains:

[image]

When highlighting, the message is simply that it "cannot instantiate".

Is that a bug in IDEA or do I miss a constructor or something?

Comment: My guess (and it is a guess) would be that IDEA doesn't know about using constructors with `@NamedArg` parameters. That was introduced in JavaFX 8 (and is basically undocumented, as far as I can tell - though pretty much everything to do with the `FXMLLoader` is undocumented).

Comment: @James_D ah, OK; so, basically, a bug should be filed at JetBrains?

Comment: Yes, probably. It would be nice if Oracle were to document this use somewhere, though. I would file a bug at JetBrains and vote for [this](https://javafx-jira.kenai.com/browse/RT-39329), and maybe [this too](https://javafx-jira.kenai.com/browse/RT-35522)

Comment: @James_D OK, I have [opened an issue](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-136393); also, while I was at it, I [opened another one](https://javafx-jira.kenai.com/browse/JMY-278) ... Not sure whether this is the correct place for it however.

Comment: I think that's appropriate; you should label it as a feature rather than a bug, though.